# append div for each data in js

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm using AJAX to append data to div element. The div class **item** style display is none because the div class only appear when the success function works.basically the div class dependent on the success function.

```
<div class="item" style="display: none;">
<div class="Name"></div> //here I want to show the success function data
<select class="price">
 <option>A</option>
 <option>B</option>
 <option>C</option></select>
</div>
```

div only shows when it finds data. I want to add data in **div class="Name"** and append each data. like when first data is added then the **item** div will show and when the 2nd data is added then 2nd data will be shown. for each data div class **item** , **Name** , **price** will appear. In this code data only appending in the same div.

```
success:function(data) {
console.log(data);
$('.item').show();
$('.Name').append(data);}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: `div only shows when it finds data`? Didn't quite get it.

Comment: You don't have to set `.item` `display: none;`. Append new `div` to `.item`'s parent container.

Comment: I mean that the div class only appears when the success function works. @weirdpanda

Answer (score 1):

Having a parent container

```
<div class="items">
</div>
```

You can use append to create new "item" elements *inside this container* using append

```
// create inner element
var newItem=$('<div class="item"></div>');
// inserting data
newItem.html(data);
// append to parent container
 $('.items').append(newItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the very simple answer here is your in-line styling. If you look at the code, you have written `display: none;`. This tells the rendering engine to hide it from the current object model.

However, when the `success` function runs, it executes `.show()` which disables `display: none;`.

To fix this,

```
<div class="items" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Then you can store that as a literal and dynamically add content using mapping like so:

```
$( '.items' ).show();
const dataHtml = '<div class="item">' + data + '</div>';
$( '.items' ).append( dataHtml );
```

---

P.S.: You can check it out [here](http://jsbin.com/wopalavoka/3/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: But the display is none because when the success function works, it will execute .show() . and when the success function won't work the div class will not appear.  and I want to show this div class for each data . @weirdpanda

Comment: I am not quite sure what you want. You want a `div` class for every item?

Comment: actually in my ajax code I am searching data .. and when the search data found , it  will show in the div element. and initially the div class will not appear until it get the  search data. @weirdpanda

Comment: Maybe we can't understand you properly. Can you explain a bit more in detail? You want each data item to have a separate 'div'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179611/discussion-between-weirdpanda-and-jan).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to append new div of items. you need to add item container which is the div with id **all_items**

```
<div id="all_items"></div>

success:function(data) {
console.log(data);
$('#all_items').append('<div class="item">+data+</div>');
}
```